# How to Specify aop.xml For ajc For Aspect Selection and Scoping

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm currently trying to instrument java classes at build time using AspectJ. To do so, I assume `ajc` (https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html) as the AspectJ compiler is a suitable tool. However, I fail to get it running on my code.

The aspect I'm trying to weave is the following: https://github.com/kieker-monitoring/kieker/blob/main/monitoring/src/kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/OperationExecutionAspectFull.java it is **bundled with other aspects in one jar**. I'm trying to instrument a **selection of classes** from the MooBench benchmark (https://github.com/kieker-monitoring/moobench/tree/main/tools/benchmark), but the same will happen to any other simple jar.

According to the documentation, I can specify the `-aspectpath` that contains the aspects that should be woven. Based on AspectJs regular process, I assumed that I can specify the aspects using `aop.xml`, which looks like this in my case (and works for load-time weaving with `-javaagent`):

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.aspectj.org/dtd/aspectj_1_5_0.dtd">
<aspectj>
  <weaver options="">
    <include within="moobench.application.*" />
  </weaver>
  <aspects>
    <aspect
      name="kieker.monitoring.probe.aspectj.operationExecution.OperationExecutionAspectFull" />
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

However, `ajc` always ignores this file. I tried to pass it as a folder directly (`-aspectpath "$(pwd)/meta-inf-classpath/:$KIEKERJAR"`, als also the same using `$(pwd)/meta-inf-classpath/META-INF` and `$(pwd)/meta-inf-classpath/META-INF/aop.xml`), or compressed as jar (`-aspectpath "$(pwd)/meta-inf-classpath.jar:$KIEKERJAR"`), but AspectJ always starts to use all aspects for instrumentation, leading to logs like these (where all aspects, including the one that won't work, are applied):

```
reichelt@reichelt-desktop:~/nvme/workspaces/kiekerworkspace/moobench/benchmark/lib$ ajc -aspectpath "$(pwd)/meta-inf-classpath.jar:/home/reichelt/.m2/repository/net/kieker-monitoring/kieker/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/kieker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-aspectj.jar" -inpath benchmark.jar 
<Unknown> [warning] Found @DeclareAnnotation while current release does not support it (see 'org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.AtAjAttributes')

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/flow/concurrency/SynchronizedAspect.java [warning] unlock() pointcut designator cannot be used without the option -Xjoinpoints:synchronization

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/flow/concurrency/SynchronizedAspect.java [warning] lock() pointcut designator cannot be used without the option -Xjoinpoints:synchronization

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/flow/concurrency/SynchronizedAspect.java [warning] lock() pointcut designator cannot be used without the option -Xjoinpoints:synchronization

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyClientInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyClientInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyClientInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientRequest [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyServerInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyServerInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyServerInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyServerInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/jersey/OperationExecutionJerseyServerInterceptor.java [warning] no match for this type name: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspectServlet.java [warning] no match for this type name: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspectServlet.java [warning] no match for this type name: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspectServlet.java [error] bad parameter to pointcut reference

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/spring/RestCommunicationAspect.java [warning] no match for this type name: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/spring/RestCommunicationAspect.java [warning] no match for this type name: org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

Therefore, this fails with an error and does not execute my instrumentation (but tries to apply the other aspects).

On the other hand, when I try to remove all aspects from the jar I do not want, I still get an error about AspectJ not able to determine precedence between two advices (1053 times):

```
[...]

/home/reichelt/.m2/repository/net/kieker-monitoring/kieker/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/kieker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-aspectj.jar!kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspect.class [error] circular advice precedence: can't determine precedence between two or more pieces of advice that apply to the same join point: method-execution(void com.beust.jcommander.validators.PositiveInteger.validate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

/home/reichelt/.m2/repository/net/kieker-monitoring/kieker/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/kieker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-aspectj.jar!kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspect.class [error] circular advice precedence: can't determine precedence between two or more pieces of advice that apply to the same join point: method-execution(void com.beust.jcommander.validators.PositiveInteger.validate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

/home/reichelt/.m2/repository/net/kieker-monitoring/kieker/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/kieker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-aspectj.jar!kieker/monitoring/probe/aspectj/operationExecution/AbstractOperationExecutionAspect.class [error] circular advice precedence: can't determine precedence between two or more pieces of advice that apply to the same join point: method-execution(void com.beust.jcommander.validators.PositiveInteger.validate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))
```

This would probably not happen if only one aspect and only the given classes would be instrumented, i.e., if the `aop.xml` would be consider. So is there any way to specify usage of an `aop.xml` in `ajc`?

Other questions ([AspectJ with aop.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214934/aspectj-with-aop-xml) and [aop.xml name and location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736860/aop-xml-name-and-location)) ask the same for load time weaving, but I'd like to do the weaving at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have been talking privately about other instrumentation-related topics before, I know part of your situation. When switching from load-time to compile-time weaving, you can simply get rid of *aop.xml* and configure your build tool - Maven ([AspectJ Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin)), Gradle ([Freefair](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.6/reference/#_aspectj)) etc. - and compile your single-module project. For a multi-module project like Kieker, you just need to make sure to put the module(s) containing aspects on the *inpath* when compiling modules to be instrumented: [AspectJ Maven](https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/libraryJars.html), [Freefair](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.6/reference/#_inpath).

I know, you are thinking about using the [`-xmlConfigured`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014) compiler parameter. I do not think, it is what you need or should use. You probably would make a simple matter complicated. I strongly recommend to rely on build tool plugins and and not to re-invent any wheels. An additional XML config file should not be necessary, if your pointcuts are well-defined and you want to apply all aspects from an aspect library to all classes targeted by their pointcuts, which in 99% of use cases should be what you want. Only if for some reason you want to only weave a [subset of aspects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121636/1082681) or use [aspect scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855840/1082681) (limit which packages an aspect with an otherwise more global pointcut is to be applied to), `-xmlConfigured` could be an option. If you were a Maven and not a Gradle user, AspectJ Maven even supports the parameter in its configuration, see [here](https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#xmlConfigured). In Freefair, probably you just add a custom command line parameter to the configuration. But like I said, probably you do not need any of this.

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Comment: Thanks! The two cases you mentioned apply: Application of one aspect from a jar with multiple aspects, and applying it only to some classes. Since aspect scoping doesn't seem to work (like you pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854550/aspectj-declare-parents-jpanel), my workaround is to extract, copy the classes-to-instrument into a new folder, call AspectJ on this folder and merge back (https://github.com/kieker-monitoring/kieker/blob/7338b61f7b41e407e1c00412110e290a753c12ec/monitoring-buildtime/src/kieker/monitoring/buildtime/BuildTimeInstrumentationAspectJ.java#L59)